# Getting "ReferenceError: PublisherCKEditorAutoComplete"

Tags: page-layout, report-chart

Getting **ReferenceError: PublisherCKEditorAutoComplete" is not defined** on account detail page on Chrome/Mozilla Browser(I have checked in both getting same issue).Please help me out.I have attached snapshot of it below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got this error today when I was uploading data via a CSV file. In our case, the CSV file had become corrupted. I had to open the original in Excel, perform a "save as" and then use the re-saved document for the upload. It worked in our case. Good luck to you....